# SQL update not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update my database using SQL commands but it is not working.

```
id = primarykey

public void updateName(int id, string name)
{ 
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE person SET name = @name where id = @id", connect()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private SqlConnection connect()
{
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var c = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    c.Open();
    return c;
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What does `connect()` do? What error or exception do you get?

Comment: connect = where i store my connectionstring. And im not getting any error. Its not updating my record.

Comment: Can you run the command in SSMS? It's probably that the record you're trying to update doesn't exist. SQL Server doesn't just ignore your commands - it either does what you tell it to, or complains that it can't.

Comment: It might not be the problem at hand, but it seems kind of odd to use a `connect()` method like that.  Why not just wrap it in another `using` statement?  Explicitly storing the connection object would feel a lot more intuitive than implicitly passing it up the stack and hoping it stays in scope.  Requiring a cognitive stop from the developer to think about it for a moment is unproductive.

Comment: More to the point of the question... What actually gets executed on the database?  Run a profiler and see what query hits the database.  As @Yuck suggests, run that same query manually and see what happens.

Comment: Check the table owner (for SQL, it could be dbo. or some user-id) and confirm the value of ID...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code we can see. So either it's not running at all, you are swallowing connection errors or most likely the record you think you are updating isn't.

Comment: Isn't this code in some kind of transaction?

Comment: could you put the code snippet of connect() ?

Comment: This seems like a problem with an obvious solution just waiting for use of SQL Profiler.

Comment: Now that I see the `connect()` method, I like it even less. `c.Open(); return c;` I'd consider that to be a code smell. The scope which opens an external resource should completely handle the lifetime of that external resource. To just return it and assume that calling code handles it is a resource leak waiting to happen.

Comment: As an alternative to using SQL Profiler (if it's unavailable for some reason), you could e.g. look at the result of `ExecuteScalar` of something like `SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = @id`.

Comment: Can you declare an int iResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); to see if there and rows affected in your command, this would give you some idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the parameters addition order - with most providers it DOES matter.

So it should be not

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
```

but rather

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

General rule: the order of calls to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` should be the same as the order of parameter occurence in the query.

Comment: For ADO .NET the order does **not** matter.

Comment: Still the same, im not gettng any error so it seems im updating another database if this is possible?

Comment: @dumbel Why would you assume it's updating another database?

Comment: Dont know, the fact that nothing is happening when executing the update and im not getting any errors, so this is just strange

Comment: @dumbel: The point we're trying to make in the comments on the question is that "nothing is happening" is an inaccurate and misleading conclusion.  _Something_ is happening.  Maybe this code is never executed by the application, maybe there's an exception that the code is ignoring, maybe the query is updating an unexpected record, etc.  But you have to debug it.  From what you've posted, there's no obvious error.  The root of the problem is outside the code snippet in the question.

Comment: Thank you, the order of parameters was my problem. I can't believe the stupidity of requiring an order for named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

- See if the DB you connect is the right DB, not test or whatever, and the same for the server
- Rewrite query as

  ```
  UPDATE person SET name = @name where id = @id; 
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    RAISERROR('No rows updated', 16,1)
  ```
- check if there are exists some empty `try ... catch{}` in call stack
- see if there exists other `person` tables in different schemas
- see if there is a trigger on the table and what it does
- see if any other processes are changing the same table
- see if an application hits this code while running